# Python For Loop Output into List

Tags: python

mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6][7,8,9],[10,11,12]]....

I need 1 element out of each index and convert it into a List. I do have more than a thousand indexes.

Should be:

newlist = [2,5,8,11]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include that in your post?

Comment: I think you might have a typo in what you've posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
newList = []

for list in mylist:
    listEntry = list[1]
    newList.append(listEntry)
    
print(newList)
```

I'm assuming you forget one comma between your second and third sublists.

Comment: upvoted since this works, but avoid using python keywords such as "list" in the code. Also, you could skip the variable assignment listEntry = list[1] and append it directly into newList.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
index = 2
print([sublist[index] for sublist in mylist])
```

outputs:

```
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Will the index change often? Might be beneficial to calculate the whole thing (you're really just asking for the "columns" of a 2D list) and then ask for whichever "index" you want. Simply take the transpose:

```py
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
>>> xt = [[*t] for t in zip(*x)]
>>> xt
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
>>> xt[1]
[2, 5, 8, 11]
```

Each subscription into the transpose `xt` gives you the whole "column" of values at that index from the original `x`.

Comment: @MS if you're satisfied, you should upvote the answers you appreciated and also mark one as correct by clicking the green check mark!